# How to convert unstructured RDD into dataframe without defining schema in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I got this following RDD after kafka streaming. I want to convert it into dataframe without defining Schema.

```
[
 {u'Enrolment_Date': u'2008-01-01', u'Freq': 78}, 
 {u'Enrolment_Date': u'2008-02-01', u'Group': u'Recorded Data'}, 
 {u'Freq': 70, u'Group': u'Recorded Data'}, 
 {u'Enrolment_Date': u'2008-04-01', u'Freq': 96}
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OrderedDict` to convert a RDD containing key value pairs to a dataframe. However, in your case not all keys are present in each row, and therefore you need to populate these first with `None` values. See the solution below

```
#Define test data
data = [{u'Enrolment_Date': u'2008-01-01', u'Freq': 78}, {u'Enrolment_Date': u'2008-02-01', u'Group': u'Recorded Data'}, {u'Freq': 70, u'Group': u'Recorded Data'}, {u'Enrolment_Date': u'2008-04-01', u'Freq': 96}]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

from pyspark.sql import Row 
from collections import OrderedDict

#Determine all the keys in the input data 
schema = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.keys()).distinct().collect()
#Add missing keys with a None value
rdd_complete= rdd.map(lambda r:{x:r.get(x) for x in schema})

#Use an OrderedDict to convert your data to a dataframe
#This ensures data ends up in the right column
df = rdd_complete.map(lambda r: Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(r.items())))).toDF()
df.show()
```

This gives as output:

```
+--------------+----+-------------+
|Enrolment_Date|Freq|        Group|
+--------------+----+-------------+
|    2008-01-01|  78|         null|
|    2008-02-01|null|Recorded Data|
|          null|  70|Recorded Data|
|    2008-04-01|  96|         null|
+--------------+----+-------------+
```